# Tab Key Causing Weird (and Unexpected) Behavior in Cygwin when SSH-ed into Server

Tags: ssh, cygwin, tab-key

This started recently and I can't really see exactly what it's doing or how it could be doing it.  I checked Accessibility Options in Windows but these are off.

When I type this command (while ssh-ed into a remote server) and then tab to auto-complete, I get weird results:

`cd /mnt-sh: <( compgen -d -- '/mnt' ): No such file or directory`

I want to tab to get options for directories in `/mnt` but this thing happens.  I Googled the result to no avail.

This only happens when ssh-ed in.  The Cygwin terminal works fine locally.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps your `$TERM` is set to something odd in the remote shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I edited `~/.bashrc` and removed the end lines regarding `bash_completion`.  Restarted the session and it was back to normal.